# Python3: Do subclasses of an abstract class inherit its magic methods?

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, subclass, magic-methods, abc

Here's the tea: I'm writing a small Monopoly game using python. I've made this little class family to represent the bills. There's a base `abstract class` called Bill which inherits from the `abc.ABC` class.

Code:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
import colorama
colorama.init(autoreset=True, strip=True)
class Bill(ABC):
  #Abstract Properties (must be overriden in subclasses)
  @property
  @abstractmethod
  def count(self):
    return 0
  @property
  @abstractmethod
  def color(self): # colorama background color
    return 0
  @property
  @abstractmethod
  def worth(self): # integer representing the bill's worth
    return 0

  # Dunder methods (The same across class family)
  def __add__(self, other):
    return self.worth + other.worth
  def __str__(self):
    return f" {self.color} {self.worth}"

class One(Bill):
  def __init__(self):
    self.__count = 0
    self.__color = "\033[0m"
    self.__worth = 0
    #super().init() ??
  # Override Abstract Methods
  @property
  def count(self):
    return self.__count
  @count.setter
  def count(self, amount):
    self.__count += 1
  @property
  def worth(self):
    return 1
  @property
  def color(self):
    return colorama.Back.WHITE
```

My question is whether my subclasses will inherit the `Bill` class's dunder methods.
And if not, do I need to include `super().__init__()` in the `One` class's `__init__` method?

Comment: Did you try to run it? If so, what happened?

Comment: @Axe319 I'm not finished with it. I'm asking because I don't want to have to rewrite half my program later on. I'm using several files here.

Comment: the reason I asked is that I pasted the code you have here, instantiated `One` with `one = One()` and printed it with `print(one)` (which calls `__str__`). So in short, running the code you posted, answers your question.